# Why is ww a linear indexed language while www is not?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I am a little bit confused on one idea regarding [indexed languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_language).

> $\{ww \mid w \in \{a,b,c\}^* \}$ is a linear indexed language, but
>
> $\{www \mid w \in \{a,b,c\}^* \}$ is not a linear indexed language.

What is the difference? As far as I know, indexed languages can be recognized by stack automatons, but I am a little confused on this.

Comment: Can you build a linear indexed grammar for $ww$? If yes, does your intuition say anything about what won't work for $www$?

Comment: Well, $ww$ works because $w^rw$ is context free ($r$ means reverse) and linear indexed grammar is in a sense able to reverse a substring. I have no formal proof that $www$ is not linear, but the intuition should probably be that first $w$ would build the stack, second $w$ would deplete it and there is nothing for the third.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Why don't you add these ideas as an answer?

Comment: @Raphael, I wouldn't want to answer without a proof. For all I know, $www$ could be linear indexed. I wonder if there is a pumping lemma for them...

Comment: Please don't change the meaning of the question. If you have another question, ask a new question. As it stands, I can't understand your edit (what's the question?)

Comment: What Juho said, plus: if what you are trying to do is erase evidence that you got help on, say, an exercise problem, note that a) by posting, you put your post under a CC license and b) [all revisions are archived](http://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/19948/revisions), anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In linear indexed languages, the intuition is that you cannot copy a big information in one step, you have to do it in aletter-by-letter way. This causes things like $ww^R$ much easier to do than $ww$. We can still do $ww$ because you can first "create" the word $w$ by pushing its letter onto the stack and writing them at the same time on the output. Then you can pop the letters to the right or to the left as you prefer, so you can always produce $ww$.
For $www$ it's not possible anymore, because after producing $w$ on the stack and writing in on the output, you need to duplicate the stack, which is not allowed. However you could produce $www^R$, by writing the letters on both sides when popping the stack.